# Как распечатать окно jFrame?

Tags: java, печать, swing

Есть прога, которая генерирует квитанцию, квитанция появляется в новом окне. Квитанцию нужно напечатать.

Comment: в каком виде в можете использовать квитанцию?

Answer (score 2):

Реализуйте интерфейс `Printable` в своем окне и печатайте на здоровье:

```
PrintRequestAttributeSet printAttributes = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
job.setPrintable(myFrame);
if (job.printDialog(printAttributes)) {
    job.print(printAttributes );
}
```